# VBA Chart x-axis not fit

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Does anyone know why my chart acts as following where the label doesn't fit to the total size?

[image: chart example]

Replaced with the hole code instead: 
As below my combobox1 contains a item that will be read from a dictionary that I can access through `mainGUI.getDiagramFunc`. chartData contains the data that is visible on the chart. chartItem is where the names is contained.

```
If ComboBox1.text = "Select item" Or ComboBox1.text = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim chartIndex As Integer
    ReDim chartItems(1) As String
    ReDim chartdata(20) As Long
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim mySeries As Series
    Dim index As Long: index = -1
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim temp As Variant: temp = split(mainGUI.getDiagramFunc.item(ComboBox1.text), ",")
    For Each value In temp
        index = index + 1
        If UBound(chartItems) <= index Then ReDim Preserve chartItems(index)
        chartItems(index) = mainGUI.getCalcKey(ComboBox1.text & "_*" & value)
    Next value

    ReDim chartdata(UBound(chartItems))
    index = -1
    For Each value In chartItems
        index = index + 1
        chartdata(index) = doCalculation(CStr(value))
    Next value
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    Set myChart = ActiveWorkbook.Charts(1)
    Set mySeries = myChart.SeriesCollection(1)

    With mySeries
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .XValues = temp
        .Values = chartdata
    End With

    Dim picFileName As String
    picFileName = "C:\Users\extmartefr\Desktop\data\mychart.gif"
    myChart.Export Filename:=picFileName, Filtername:="GIF"
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(picFileName)
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: First, I'll help by removing the irrelevant code from your question. (comments and export code).  Your code doesn't include the important stuff, like ***where is the data coming from?***, as well as "what have you tried"?  ...Please see "[ask]" as well as how to make an **[mcve]**.  Also some great tips from [so]'s top user [**here**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Also, `.Values = .Values` does absolutely nothing.  You kind of need to start over from the too. Perhaps, get the chart working manually before attempting it with VBA.

Comment: @ashleedawg I'm sorry, updated the question with the hole code instead. Thanks for the links, gonna read them in a sec. Everything is working except the scaling for the bars. I think the error occurs when I try to access a existing chart but not sure why it doesnt work.

Comment: What is `ComboBox1.Text`? I presume it is a comma-delimited list, and Split produces a variable `temp` which is an array of the items in the list. But you obviously have many more items than data points for the columns to plot, most likely a whole lot of empty values.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @ashleedawg that your question is not particularly clear.  However, I thnk I can help.

Try adding a line of code that detects your max value and sets the x-axis maximum like this:

```
myChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = (Your code to determine max x-value)
```

Comment: A column chart's X axis is a text axis, that is, its labels are non-numerical. Therefore, there is no MinimumScale or MacimumScale property.